# How to create a shadows pass in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

Everytime I am doing one thing another problem comes up, and I have a deadline to follow unless there is a way to create shadows using another software (after effects)? I want to composite this thing in after effects but I cannot do something simple like a shadows pass. I followed the shadows pass tutorials but of course nothing works. Here is my node setup:

[image: as the backdrop shows, there is only black]

[image]

here are other settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

an update to my node setup:

[image]

Comment: any more answers

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3002/599

Comment: Note that if all you want is a shadow pass that includes everything in the scene, you don't need a second renderlayer. You can just enable the shadow pass on the character layer.

Comment: I tried that and nothing worked. Maybe I should continue this without shadow. But it will look weird.

Comment: Hmm. What precisely didn't work? Could you upload your .blend?

Comment: the shadow finally appeared but now the background image is not showing even when I render it, it is transparent. here is a larger image http://i.stack.imgur.com/55HVu.png

Comment: Try using an *Alpha Over* node in place of the *Overlay* node

Comment: shadow still doesn't show up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example for using Shadow pass in your case:

[image]

I personally prefer combining shadow with other passes like AO, for better result.

Comment: it still didn't work. I see the background but not the character and the shadow.

Comment: @user2883800 Would you like to share with the .blend file? You needn't pack all source data, but should be with same settings.

Comment: it worked. I needed to ad an extra node that was used in another tutorial. I just placed it on there randomly and the shadow appeared. thank you.

Comment: **Please** help future users by telling us what node you added and where you put it. (If you just randomly put it somewhere and it worked, then it was probably a viewer node, which is not required for the final compositing).

Comment: I used the image scale node and connected to the image node.