# Compositing with Shadows and resources

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I would like to know how to composite a shadow in Cycles. The diffuse already has a shadow. I did the add and then multiply of the three diffuse passes. (Direct, Indirect and color) that is recommended in the official manual.

Also, I would like to know where a book can be found for compositing with Cycles. The official documentation is good, but is in small chunks. Please do not recommend the usual video tutorials. Hopefully someone can write an in depth book about professional compositing that is not about Blender Internal. Like the compositing book by the Blender Foundation when they used internal for Big Buck Bunny.

Comment: Might be helpful to add some screenshots or a blend file showing what you have already done/want.

Comment: What I am saying is that the diffuse pass already has a shadow in Cycles once I combine the direct, indirect and color. In internal the diffuse pass has no shadows. That is when you add a multiply and the shadow pass. What I want to do is do cartoon or pixar like renders and then have control over the shadows. All of the tutorials are for compositing into realistic scenes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.. A diffuse pass with no shadows? Or a shadow only pass? Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5084/599,  http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3002/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3095/599