# Blender internal - pure white plane with shadows/gloss

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, shaders, shadows

I'm trying to do something like this in Blender internal renderer:

[image]

Here are some Cycles-solution using, which I'm trying to replicate in Internal:

- [How do I make a pure white plane that receives shadows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49370/how-do-i-make-a-pure-white-plane-that-receives-shadows)
- [Render shadow on transparent background with Blender Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/render-shadow-on-transparent-background-with-blender-render)

I will be making something very simple, with bouncing balls etc, so I don't need the realistic features of Cycles, and like the render speed of Internal.

So how would I do to make everything white, and only cast simple shadows? So it's kind of like a light box, with only my objects in focus.

I've tried make a bent plane, but it doesn't look white.

[image: 2]

I also tried a white Horizon color but this affects the lighting in the scene.

[image: 3]

I appreciate any help, and if you can point me to some good material/lighting tutorials for Blender Internal, it would really help. It's so hard to google it, due to the generic name, and most tutorials I can find is using Cycles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use "**Shadows Only**" option in the **material's** shadow **settings**
[image]

and set **horizon color to white** in the World tab.

The result looks like this:
[image]

This is the blend with such simple setup (I have also enabled Ambient Occlusion effect in the World settings).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. At first everything was white, but I realized I forgot to add the plane. :)

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to do this without Ambient Occlusion, and by just using lamps instead to get simple shadows, instead of the more realistic shadows, but still have everything white in the background/plane?

Comment: Of course, just add some Lamp (for example a sun) and activate Ray Shadow in it's settings.