# How to composite shadow pass with image sequences?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes, shadows

I rendered passes from a scene in another program and wanted to use Blender to composite them. What is the node setup for combining a diffuse color pass and shadow pass into one image? Thanks!

Color:
[image]

Shadow:
[image]

Comment: Please add example images for the passes you want to combine. The node setup may vary depending on how your shadow pass looks like.

Comment: You usually use a mix node set to multiply

Comment: Color example: http://i.imgur.com/QkKrEL4.png
Shadow example: http://i.imgur.com/CYmqE0x.png

They would be a series of images like these. Thanks for the help!

@Bithur I'll try that. : )

Comment: This doesn't look like a shadow pass, it's a render with shadows, with a deactivated layer. try this trick :http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3003/11431 an use a "real" shadow pass (check shadow in render passes)