# Make a mesh inside another mesh appear over the the outer mesh

Tags: rendering, mesh

I'm trying to make an effect similar to this but in blender instead of unity :
[image: bladeinunity]

The darker inner part is a cylinder which is inside a larger cylinder with inverted normals and a solid blue material, which makes a solid blue outline around the smaller cylinder. How can I achieve this in blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/transparency-masking-see-through-an-outer-sphere-and-see-inner-sphere-in-true/70619#70619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cycles I use this setup (not mine, but I can't remember where i found it) :

[image]

You can also use Freestyle, it's a different approach but gives a lot of control over the edge style, thickness etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using Eevee you can turn on *'backface culling'* for the outer (larger) mesh:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. I'd prefer to use cycles for this. is it possible using cycles?

Comment: @Mdot I don't think so since Cycles is physically accurate... However you can render only the inside object with transparent background in a separate view layer and add it back with an "alpha over" node in the compositing workspace. If you only want the solid outline you should look into "freestyle" strokes