# How do you make an object completely invisible from the outside?

Tags: rendering, materials, objects, 3d-view

I have this half-sphere that I want the inside to be visible and the outside to be invisible. I've been trying to do this with blackface culling, but at certain angles, I can still see the inside from the outside.

[image]

*image from the front view*

[image]

*image from the back view*

As you can see, from the back you can still see some of the inside. Is there a way to make it non-visible from the back? Is it possible to mask the material?

Comment: You might need to use camera angle and compare it with the object to make it disappear when looking it from back

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70576/transparency-masking-see-through-an-outer-sphere-and-see-inner-sphere-in-true/70619#70619

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think the OP is aware of Backface culling. The problem come to the half sphere will let part of the ball being front-face, which are not desired result.